# Best pattern to track actions inside a presenter

Tags: design-patterns

I have a MVP implementation, inside my presenter i have a lot of public methods like onSendMessage() for example.

I need to track some of that methods, meaning track just call a trackClient.trackSendMessage().

That actions could be over 20 more or less and i dont want to make dirty my presenter with a bit of logic about should track whatever action or not.
Some of that actions will need logic about current view status like if its visible whatever think or not.

What pattern do you think i should use here?Maybe a decorator?

Comment: Whatever works.  Pattern-Driven-Development is the same thing as cargo-cult development.

Comment: So, in essence, you are looking for a way to add logging (tracking) to your application and don't want to add more complexity to your structure?

Comment: Basically, i don't want to change my current presenter implementación to add logic about tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to add caching, data validation, monitoring, persistance or indeed logging not just to a specific class or method, but to a whole range of them throughout your application, this is called a [cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern).

I can think of no software pattern that solves this problem cleanly. And though the Decorator is a fine pattern, you will find it lacking for these problems.

One way to deal with cross-cutting concerns without breaking all structures in your application, is by applying [Aspect-oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (AOP).

The basic premise of AOP is not to copy the code that handles the cross-cutting concern in each seperate place you want to use it (violating the DRY-principle many times over), but rather write it once and specify where you want it to be injected.

For instance you could make a log function that logs all parameters for any function which name starts with "set". It depends on the specific framework how this is achieved and the notation for specifying where the code is injected (the code is called ["advice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(programming)), the point you are looking for in your query is called ["pointcut"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointcut) and the points in your main code that match the query are called ["join points"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_point)).
Generally the AOP framework will use

There are various AOP frameworks for various programming environments.